# forgot Apple ID after restoring iphone

Tags: apple-id

I reset my phone. then when it finally turned back on after restoring itself, it asked for my Apple ID and the password. I forget both of them . it will not let me into the phone without imputing that information, which I don't have. 
is there a way to get into my phone so I can use it again without knowing it ?

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you did not remove your AppleID from the phone before resetting it, then it is still bound to that ID for security reasons.

You can try and use this site from Apple to help figure out what your Apple ID was and reset the password...

https://iforgot.apple.com/appleid#!&section=appleid